# jQuery scroll to a certain point using mouse wheel

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

i found a JSFiddle that works perfectly for using an automatic scroll between divs.
This is the script:http://jsfiddle.net/Sg8JQ/

```
/* I'm including the minified script by Brandom Aaron here since I can't find
** a reliable host. Obviously, you can just link to his script later on.
*/





/*! Copyright (c) 2011 Brandon Aaron (http://brandonaaron.net)
 * Licensed under the MIT License (LICENSE.txt).
 *
 * Thanks to: http://adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/ for some pointers.
 * Thanks to: Mathias Bank(http://www.mathias-bank.de) for a scope bug fix.
 * Thanks to: Seamus Leahy for adding deltaX and deltaY
 *
 * Version: 3.0.6
 * 
 * Requires: 1.2.2+
 */
(function(a){function d(b){var c=b||window.event,d=[].slice.call(arguments,1),e=0,f=!0,g=0,h=0;return b=a.event.fix(c),b.type="mousewheel",c.wheelDelta&&(e=c.wheelDelta/120),c.detail&&(e=-c.detail/3),h=e,c.axis!==undefined&&c.axis===c.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(h=0,g=-1*e),c.wheelDeltaY!==undefined&&(h=c.wheelDeltaY/120),c.wheelDeltaX!==undefined&&(g=-1*c.wheelDeltaX/120),d.unshift(b,e,g,h),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,d)}var b=["DOMMouseScroll","mousewheel"];if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var c=b.length;c;)a.event.fixHooks[b[--c]]=a.event.mouseHooks;a.event.special.mousewheel={setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.addEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=d},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var a=b.length;a;)this.removeEventListener(b[--a],d,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null}},a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})})(jQuery)





// Relevant code    

var lastAnimation = 0;
var animationTime = 1000; // in ms
var quietPeriod = 500; // in ms, time after animation to ignore mousescroll

function scrollThis(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

    // change this to deltaX/deltaY depending on which
    // scrolling dir you want to capture
    deltaOfInterest = deltaY;

    if (deltaOfInterest == 0) {
        // Uncomment if you want to use deltaX
        // event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
    if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + animationTime) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if (deltaOfInterest < 0) {
        if ($('.active').next('div').length) {
            lastAnimation = timeNow;
            $('.active').removeClass('active').next('div').addClass('active');
            $('html,body').animate( {
                scrollTop: $('.active').offset().top }, animationTime);
        }
    } else {
        if ($('.active').prev('div').length) {
            lastAnimation = timeNow;
            $('.active').removeClass('active').prev('div').addClass('active');
            $('html,body').animate( {
                scrollTop: $('.active').offset().top }, animationTime);
        }
    }
}

$(document).mousewheel(scrollThis);
```

The only problem for my site is that script involves every div of the website.
In my case, i got a principal div with inside other 2 divs.
What happen is i've to use 3 times the mousewheel before scroll down to the second big div.

**HTML STRUCTURE**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="nav_icon">
        <a href="#" id="trigger-overlay"><img src="img/nav_icon.png" title="Menu di Navigazione" class="nav_icon"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="intro" class="active">
        <img src="img/logo_big.png" title="Attico Immobiliare - Agenzia Immobiliare Rovigo" class="logo_big">
        <img src="img/logo_small.png" title="Attico Immobiliare - Agenzia Immobiliare Rovigo" class="logo_small">
        <div id="intro_content">
            <div id="slogan">
                <p>WE <span style="font-weight:500;">LOVE</span> WHAT <em><span style="font-weight:300;">WE DO</span></em> AND <em><span style="font-weight:300;">WE DO IT</span></em> WITH <span style="font-weight:700;">MORE</span> <span style="font-weight:400;">PASSION</span></p>
            </div>
            <div id="search_form">
                <?php include('form_ricerca.php'); ?>
                <div id="bottoni_ricerca">
                    <div class="button_search affitto"></div>
                    <div class="button_search vendita"></div>
                    <div class="button_search codice"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('intro_mobile.php'); ?>

    <div id="last_insert">
    <div id="slides">
        <nav class="slides-navigation">
          <a href="#" class="next">
           <img src="img/slide_next.png" title="Immobile successivo" onMouseOver="this.src='img/slide_next_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/slide_next.png'">
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="prev">
            <img src="img/slide_prev.png" title="Immobile successivo" onMouseOver="this.src='img/slide_prev_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/slide_prev.png'">
          </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="team">
        <div id="team_intro">
            <p>Siamo un gruppo di agenti immobiliari regolarmente iscritti e costantemente aggiornati sulle nuove norme in vigore. Questo lavoro è la nostra passione, e mettiamo anima e corpo in ciò che facciamo.</p>
        </div>
        <h2>il team</h2>
        <p class="testo_about">Cerchiamo, attingendo dalle nostre conoscenze, di soddisfare le richieste dei nostri clienti, facendo in modo che si instauri un rapporto di fiducia non a senso unico, ma da entrambe le direzioni. L'amore verso la casa e l'immobile ci spinge a dare sempre il massimo perchè ogni trattativa si concluda nel migliore dei modi.<br /><br /><span class="testo_hidden">Crediamo ancora nella vecchia stretta di mano e in ciò che esiste oltre al classico rapporto tra agente immobiliare e il cliente. Cerchiamo di portar a termine affari col sorriso e con la TRASPARENZA ASSOLUTA assieme alla giusta dose di tranquillità necessaria perchè entrambe le parti concludano soddisfatte la propria giornata.</span></p>
        <a href="about.php">il team</a>
    </div>

    <div id="network">
        <video id="Video1" loop autobuffer="autobuffer" preload autoplay> 
            <source src="video/video_home_page_attico_2014.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <!--<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
                <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            </object>
        </video>
        <div id="network_content">
            <img src="img/network_divider.jpg" class="network_divider">
            <h3>attico immobiliare network</h3>
            <p>Attico Immobiliare è presente su tutti i Social Network più popolari. Seguici nel canale che preferisci per avere sempre aggiornamenti riguardo la disponibilità dei nsotri immobili. Troverai inoltre tante altre curiiosità riguardo il mondo della casa!</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/atticoimmobiliare" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_facebook.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_facebook_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_facebook.png'" title="Seguici su Facebook"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://twitter.com/ATTICO_agenzia" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_twitter.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_twitter_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_twitter.png'" title="Seguici su Twitter"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://plus.google.com/100926148658161455340/posts" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_google.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_google_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_google.png'" title="Seguici su Google+"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/davpole" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_youtube.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_youtube_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_youtube.png'" title="Seguici su Youtube"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/atticoimm/" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_pinterest.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_pinterest_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_pinterest.png'" title="Seguici su Pinterest"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://it.linkedin.com/pub/attico-immobiliare-rovigo/71/420/a37" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_linkedin.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_linkedin_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_linkedin.png'" title="Seguici su Linkedin"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <a href="http://web.casaconvenienza.net" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo_casaconvenienza_network.png" title="Casa Convenienza - Immobili Low Cost" class="casaconv_network"></a>
            <p>Prende vita Casa Convenienza, il nostro brand dedicato alla gestione degli immobili a basso prezzo. Dai un'occhiata per trovare la miglior offerta disponibile sul mercato!</p>
            <div id="network_buttons">
                <a href="http://web.casaconvenienza.net" target="_blank" class="left">immobiliare low cost</a>
                <a href="http://shop.casaconvenienza.net" target="_blank" class="right">e-commerce</a>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
</div>
```

The divs i need to be affect from the script are intro, last_insert, team, network and footer.

I need an help to change this code to works only for divs with a fixed class.
Is that possible?

Comment: Can you add your html structure?

Comment: HTML structure added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike,

You can simply add a common class to your interesting divs (intro, last_insert, team, network and footer), named `scrollableBlock` for example, and then use the modified script where you use your className instead of `div` in the jquery selectors.

Here is a working sample (works directly by copying and saving it as an html file, I added the links to the scripts you used instead of copying it). I also added paragraph to enlight the start of the div where I am scrolling

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.11/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Relevant code
            var lastAnimation = 0;
            var animationTime = 1000; // in ms
            var quietPeriod = 500; // in ms, time after animation to ignore mousescroll

            function scrollThis(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
                var timeNow = new Date().getTime();

                // change this to deltaX/deltaY depending on which
                // scrolling dir you want to capture
                deltaOfInterest = deltaY;

                if (deltaOfInterest == 0) {
                    // Uncomment if you want to use deltaX
                    // event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }

                // Cancel scroll if currently animating or within quiet period
                if(timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + animationTime) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }

                if (deltaOfInterest < 0) {
                    if ($('.active').nextAll('.scrollableBlock:first').length) {
                        lastAnimation = timeNow;
                        $('.active').removeClass('active').nextAll('.scrollableBlock:first').addClass('active');
                        $('html,body').animate( {
                            scrollTop: $('.active').offset().top }, animationTime);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($('.active').prevAll('.scrollableBlock:first').length) {
                        lastAnimation = timeNow;
                        $('.active').removeClass('active').prevAll('.scrollableBlock:first').addClass('active');
                        $('html,body').animate( {
                            scrollTop: $('.active').offset().top }, animationTime);
                    }
                }
            }

            $(document).mousewheel(scrollThis);
        </script>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="nav_icon">
                <a href="#" id="trigger-overlay"><img src="img/nav_icon.png" title="Menu di Navigazione" class="nav_icon" /></a>
            </div>

            <div id="intro" class="active scrollableBlock">
                <p>START OF INTRO DIV</p>
                <img src="img/logo_big.png" title="Attico Immobiliare - Agenzia Immobiliare Rovigo" class="logo_big" />
                    <img src="img/logo_small.png" title="Attico Immobiliare - Agenzia Immobiliare Rovigo" class="logo_small" />
                <div id="intro_content">
                    <div id="slogan">
                        <p>WE <span style="font-weight:500;">LOVE</span> WHAT <em><span style="font-weight:300;">WE DO</span></em> AND <em><span style="font-weight:300;">WE DO IT</span></em> WITH <span style="font-weight:700;">MORE</span> <span style="font-weight:400;">PASSION</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="search_form">
                        <?php include('form_ricerca.php'); ?>
                        <div id="bottoni_ricerca">
                            <div class="button_search affitto"></div>
                            <div class="button_search vendita"></div>
                            <div class="button_search codice"></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php include('intro_mobile.php'); ?>

            <div id="last_insert" class="scrollableBlock">
                <p>START OF LAST INSERT DIV</p>
                <div id="slides">
                    <nav class="slides-navigation">
                      <a href="#" class="next">
                          <img src="img/slide_next.png" title="Immobile successivo" onMouseOver="this.src='img/slide_next_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/slide_next.png'" />
                      </a>
                      <a href="#" class="prev">
                          <img src="img/slide_prev.png" title="Immobile successivo" onMouseOver="this.src='img/slide_prev_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/slide_prev.png'" />
                      </a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="team" class="scrollableBlock">
                <div id="team_intro">
                    <p>START OF TEAM DIV</p>
                    <p>Siamo un gruppo di agenti immobiliari regolarmente iscritti e costantemente aggiornati sulle nuove norme in vigore. Questo lavoro è la nostra passione, e mettiamo anima e corpo in ciò che facciamo.</p>
                </div>
                <h2>il team</h2>
                <p class="testo_about">Cerchiamo, attingendo dalle nostre conoscenze, di soddisfare le richieste dei nostri clienti, facendo in modo che si instauri un rapporto di fiducia non a senso unico, ma da entrambe le direzioni. L'amore verso la casa e l'immobile ci spinge a dare sempre il massimo perchè ogni trattativa si concluda nel migliore dei modi.<br /><br /><span class="testo_hidden">Crediamo ancora nella vecchia stretta di mano e in ciò che esiste oltre al classico rapporto tra agente immobiliare e il cliente. Cerchiamo di portar a termine affari col sorriso e con la TRASPARENZA ASSOLUTA assieme alla giusta dose di tranquillità necessaria perchè entrambe le parti concludano soddisfatte la propria giornata.</span></p>
                <a href="about.php">il team</a>
            </div>

            <div id="network" class="scrollableBlock">
                <p>START OF NETWORK DIV</p>
                <video id="Video1" loop autobuffer="autobuffer" preload autoplay> 
                    <source src="video/video_home_page_attico_2014.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    <!--<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
                    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />-->
                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
                        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
                        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    </object>
                </video>
                <div id="network_content">
                    <img src="img/network_divider.jpg" class="network_divider">
                    <h3>attico immobiliare network</h3>
                    <p>Attico Immobiliare è presente su tutti i Social Network più popolari. Seguici nel canale che preferisci per avere sempre aggiornamenti riguardo la disponibilità dei nsotri immobili. Troverai inoltre tante altre curiiosità riguardo il mondo della casa!</p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/atticoimmobiliare" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_facebook.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_facebook_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_facebook.png'" title="Seguici su Facebook" /></a></td>
                            <td><a href="https://twitter.com/ATTICO_agenzia" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_twitter.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_twitter_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_twitter.png'" title="Seguici su Twitter" /></a></td>
                            <td><a href="https://plus.google.com/100926148658161455340/posts" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_google.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_google_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_google.png'" title="Seguici su Google+" /></a></td>
                            <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/davpole" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_youtube.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_youtube_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_youtube.png'" title="Seguici su Youtube" /></a></td>
                            <td><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/atticoimm/" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_pinterest.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_pinterest_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_pinterest.png'" title="Seguici su Pinterest" /></a></td>
                            <td><a href="http://it.linkedin.com/pub/attico-immobiliare-rovigo/71/420/a37" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_linkedin.png" onMouseOver="this.src='img/social_linkedin_hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='img/social_linkedin.png'" title="Seguici su Linkedin" /></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        <a href="http://web.casaconvenienza.net" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo_casaconvenienza_network.png" title="Casa Convenienza - Immobili Low Cost" class="casaconv_network" /></a>
                    <p>Prende vita Casa Convenienza, il nostro brand dedicato alla gestione degli immobili a basso prezzo. Dai un'occhiata per trovare la miglior offerta disponibile sul mercato!</p>
                    <div id="network_buttons">
                        <a href="http://web.casaconvenienza.net" target="_blank" class="left">immobiliare low cost</a>
                        <a href="http://shop.casaconvenienza.net" target="_blank" class="right">e-commerce</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your method by myself before asking here, but the script stop wirking now... Don't know why, but if I modify the div destination with a class it doesn't work anymore.

But the fiddle modified like you did works!

Comment: Ok i'm looking for another solution

Comment: Mike, I updated the solution and checked well: it's working for me like that. You can test by copying the code and save it to a html file and directly test (jquery & mousewheel plugin included at the beginning of the doc)

Comment: And sorry I did not read your initial comment correctly I thought you said it was not working. Is it ok for you now? You also should call the CDN of the mousewheel plugin script instead of copying it

Comment: What do you mean with "call the CDN instead copying it"? I tried to copy the script inside my .js file, included both jquery and jquery-mousewheel. It didn't work inside my web site, i really don't know why... I tried commentingall the script, no way... I'll try again later, addindg a piece of code at time

Comment: it's just the way I reference the script: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.11/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>`.

Note that in my sample, the custom script for the scroll is not in the `head`

Comment: i moved the custom script at the bottom page before </body>, there's no way it works... If you want to look the entire code the web site is http://attico-immobiliare.it/

Comment: Mike, I got it! This is due to the `next` and `prev` used, because it is trying to check the selector just on the 1st next/prev item. In fact, use .`prevAll('.scrollableBlock:first')` and `nextAll('.scrollableBlock:first')`. I edited the answer

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN! It works! Yeah! Finally i can take my money!! xD Thanks for your help and time Nicolas, you become an essential part of the project! THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome, happy to see it helped you. And I also learned some things about jquery and how these div scrolling can be made ;)